# std::thread won't get my cpu over 20% load?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, rendering, sfml

Maybe i am using std::thread wrong?
I have a 12 thread cpu and built a render engine. More like a plotter for stuff like perlin noise etc...
Since rendering was quite slow, i used std::thread, to make full use of my 12 cores. The rendering speed actually increased dramatically but my cpu usage won't go any higher than it would by just using one thread....

This is my code responsible for the rendering... let me try to explain it...

```
void Renderer::Render(sf::Image * _img,
                      sf::Vector2f _dims,
                      unsigned _threadCount)
{
    im = _img;
    dims = _dims;

    im->create(dims.x, dims.y, sf::Color(100, 0, 0, 255));

    static float bar = 0.3f;
    float g = 0.01f;

    std::vector < std::thread > workers;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < _threadCount; ++i)
    {
        workers.push_back(std::thread(Renderer::RenderThread,
                                      sf::IntRect((dims.x / _threadCount) * i,
                                                  0,
                                                  (dims.x / _threadCount) * (i + 1),
                                                  dims.y),
                                      bar,
                                      g,
                                      sf::Color(0,
                                                (255.0f / _threadCount) * i,
                                                0)));
    }

    bar += 0.01f;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < workers.size(); ++i)
    {
        workers[i].join();
    }

    return;
}

void Renderer::RenderThread(sf::IntRect area, float bar, float g, sf::Color clr)
{
    for (unsigned x = area.left + 1; x < area.width + 1; x++)
    {
        for (unsigned y = area.top + 1; y < area.height + 1; y++)
        {
            im->setPixel(x - 1, y - 1, ImAlg::Tiles0(x, y, bar, 5));
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

So basically what it does is the following:
The upper function is the main function, which gets called by the framework.
It creates the threads.
The lower function is the function that runs on every thread.
I tried to divide the image to be rendered into even parts.
Like if the image was 1000 wide and i'd use 4 threads, every thread would render
250x1000 px

Comment: Are you testing release / optimized build? I have seen cases where it took 100 times longer in debug mode.

Comment: In `Render::Render` you are creating and destroying `_threadCount` threads every call.  Creating threads is a very expensive task.  Look into using a thread pool and handing work tasks to them.

Comment: It could be the image is so small that the cost of creating these threads is significant to the amount of work done in each thread.

Comment: With modern C++ (post the epic revival that was C++11) thread pools for dispatching work items to reusable *already running* threads just waiting for something to do only takes a few dozen lines of code. Seriously consider what Richard is saying.

Comment: Perhaps you need to tell us what tool you are using to determine the '20% load'.  Using the 'top' utility (Ubuntu 18.04): my 'Hailstone'  C++ app shows 100% using 1 thread (run time 44 seconds), and (a different run) 200% using two threads (taking 22 seconds).  [on my older two core desktop].  Your code (what you have shared) looks ok to me.

Comment: That sounds like windows task manager. In windows 100% means all cores are fully loaded.

Comment: Does this 'multi-thread' code 'work' when (_threadcount == 1)?

Comment: "small that the cost of creating these threads is significant"  Good idea.  How long does your code run with 1, 2, 4, and 12 threads?  With no interference between them, should not 2 threads complete in half the time of 1?

Comment: it does run on 1 thread.   No, i don't think that the cost of creating the threads is causing the problem because these pictures are 4k pictures. Hence each frame still takes a few seconds to compute. It seems like the workload is spreaded equally. Hence, 2 threads is twice as fast as one thread, 4 are four times as fast, etc..

Comment: @WhozCraig Does c++ finally have a standard thread pool implementation? Or is this once again a "only a few lines of code and this gigantic library that only supports platform X"? We had the latter for much longer than c++11.

Comment: @Voo C++ 11 has standard library thread support, atomics, futures, concurrency control, *all* in the standard library (which is long driver and a wedge farther down the fairway then we *ever* were with the likes of things like pthreads and, shudder.. windows threads). A thread pool can be tossed together that runs on *all* C++11 and later compliant platforms easily.

Comment: "it does run on 1 thread. "  Kudos.   "2 threads is twice as fast as one thread"  Interesting ...  now, what is the load with 1 thread? what is the load reported with 2 threads? ... is the 20% load on the 12 thread scenario? and so 1 thread is very small loading?  Or is the loading 20% regardless of how many threads are running?  How are you measuring the load?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use raw threads.  Start with a simple thread pool:

```
struct thread_pool {
  std::future<void> run( std::function<void()> f ){
    std::packaged_task<void()> t(std::move(f));
    auto r = t.get_future();
    auto l = lock();
    q.push_back(std::move(t));
    cv.notify_one();
    return r;
  }
  void start(std::size_t n){
    //std::cout << n << " threads starting" << std::endl;
    while(n--)
      threads.push_back( std::thread([this]{loop();}) );
   }
  ~thread_pool(){
    end();
    for (auto&&t:threads)t.join();
  }
private:
  void end(){
    auto n=threads.size();
    auto l=lock();
    for(auto count=n;count;--count)
      q.emplace_back();
    cv.notify_all();
    //std::cout << n << " threads ended" << std::endl;
  }
  void loop(){
    while(true){
      //std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::endl;
      auto t=pop();
      //std::cout << "Got " << t.valid() << std::endl;
      if (!t.valid()) break;
      //std::cout << "Running..." << std::endl;
      t();
    }
  }
  std::packaged_task<void()> pop(){
    auto l=lock();
    cv.wait(l, [&]{ return !q.empty();});
    auto r = std::move(q.front());
    q.pop_front();
    return r;
  }
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;

  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(){ return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m); }
  std::mutex m;
  std::deque<std::packaged_task<void()>> q;
  std::condition_variable cv;
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3978b0d92be1b00).

Use a thread pool; pass in to the code that needs threads, with threads pre-started (maybe based on hardware concurrency).  `run` tasks.  Wait on the returned future from the run methods.

It will be much faster than spinning up threads on demand.